# Limiting joined entities with Doctrine's DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, dql

I want to reduce the amount of load on the database by limiting the number of joined entities.

As an example, say I have a Category entity with a many-to-one relationship to a Product entity. Then on a summary page I only want to show the first 5 products of each category. How would I write the DQL for that?

I could obviously just call `$category->getProducts()` and only show the first five, but that feels wasteful. I'm not sure if Symfony2 / Doctrine does some magic in the background to improve on that, but it still feels like there should be a better way to limit the number of joined entities. I've also tried using `->setMaxResults()` but that won't help me.

Comment: You can limited result rows, not only joined. If you want to limit joined, you must to use subquery

Answer (score 0):

With Doctrine you can use [EntityRepository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes), where you can write your own improved query, not simply call `$category->getProducts()`.

For DQL do something like

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT p
    FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
    JOIN AcmeStoreBundle:Category c
    WHERE p.price > :price
    ORDER BY p.price ASC
')->setParameter('price', '19.99');

$products = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I know, I was asking for help with writing the DQL for it.

Comment: For it you must to show tables, that you want to joined

Comment: Thanks, but I have used DQL before. I'm just wondering how I could limit the products that are joined on the third line of your query. I don't want to return all of them, and in my situation there is no where condition I could use that would help reduce the number.

Comment: But it isn't a `JOIN` tasks. Read about [JOIN](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) and when it used

Comment: I'm not asking how to do it with an actual JOIN, I'm just describing what I want to accomplish with DQL.